# Jupyter Windows Matlab Dead Kernel - Path Issue

Tags: windows, matlab, jupyter

I'm getting a dead kernel problem with running jupyter with matlab, in windows 7.  I can run jupyter fine with R, OCTAVE and PYTHON, but MATLAB I get this error:

error: matlabserver: could not find library or dependents: C:\Users\username\AppD
ata\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymatbridge/matlab\messenger.mex

error: called from
    matlabserver at line 7 column 1

I don't know why there's a forward slash instead of a backslash at ...pymatbridge/matlab...

and I can't find which file I need to open to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you confirm that the messenger.mex file actually exists (and that you have pymatbridge installed). Has MATLAB worked with Jupyter in the past, and only recently stopped working?

Comment: Yes it is located in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pymatbridge\matlab."   And pymatbridge is install.  It recently stopped working, after I installed the octave_kernel, and I upgraded nbformat.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE system variable was somehow interferring.  I deleted it and the matlab kernel works.  To run an octave notebook I need to set the variable locally in a command prompt session before launching jupyter.